# PHP - Import csv into database data too long

Tags: php, mysql, file, csv, fgetcsv

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to save records into database with php. I used the sql method `LOAD DATA INFILE` but it didn't work anyway.

Index.php has the form with `<input name='csv' type='file' id='csv'/>`.

My file upload has 5 strings columns and 2 integers (last of them), moreover it has only two rows, header and values.

They are the fields `NOT NULL` in 'usuarios' database.
So here's the problem, when I trying to add a record (for instance: 'bea') it says that

> .....(sooo long)......K8docProps/app.xmlPK Data too long for column 'NombreUsuario' at row 1

Yeah, readfile shows that, so I changed the details of every column (I don't think it was the problem) and put values `VARCHAR(200) / INTEGER(200)`, whatever it doesn't let me put more length because I tried `Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`.

And here's my code, I made it with others examples:

#### subirCSV.php

```
    
    require ('../cabses.php');
    require ('../conecta.php');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])) {
            echo "File ". $_FILES['csv']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.";
            echo "Displaying contents:";
            readfile($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);
        }
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
        $flag = true;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, " ")) !== FALSE) {
            if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
            $import="INSERT INTO usuarios (NombreUsuario,PassUsuario,EmailUsuario,Nombre,Apellidos,IdPropietario,IdRol) VALUES 
                            (
                                '".trim($data[0], '"')."',
                                '".trim($data[1], '"')."', 
                                '".trim($data[2], '"')."',
                                '".trim($data[3], '"')."',
                                '".trim($data[4], '"')."', 
                                '".trim($data[5], '"')."',
                                '".trim($data[6], '"')."'
                            )
                        ";
            $oConni->query($import) or die(mysqli_error($oConni)."____________".$import);
        }
        fclose($handle);
        print "Import done";
    } else {
        print "Not working";
    }
```

Maybe it was for the UTF-8 encode?

This is my first question in StackOverFlow, so hello everybody from Spain! And thank you!

Comment: Sidenote : `MD5` isn't a good/secure hashing method for storing passwords. Please refer to [password_hash()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally finished it! First at all I realized that the separator was `;` and with `addslashes($data[0])` works fine.

You can use my code and try it.

```
    require ('../conecta.php');
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])) {
                $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
                $flag = true;
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
                    if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }
                    $sql="INSERT INTO usuarios (NombreUsuario,PassUsuario,EmailUsuario,Nombre,Apellidos,IdPropietario,IdRol) VALUES 
                                    (
                                        '".addslashes($data[0])."',
                                        '".addslashes(md5($data[1]))."',
                                        '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                                        '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                                        '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                                        '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                                        '".addslashes($data[6])."'
                                    )
                                ";
                    $oConni->query($sql);
                }
                fclose($handle);
                header('Location:../index.php');
            } else {
                print "No funciona";
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
     $filename_csv = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($filename_csv);
    if($extension=="csv")
    {
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");

        while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {

        $sql = mysql_query("insert into upload_data(spent,click,filename,date) values('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]')") or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_query($sql);
        }
        fclose($file);
        echo $error1=ucwords('<div style="margin-left:60px;position: absolute;width: 400px; color: #006400;">CSV File has been successfully Imported</div>');

        }
        }
        else
        {
        echo $error1=ucwords('<div style="margin-left:60px;position: absolute;width: 400px; color: #CC0000;">Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File</div>');
       // echo 'Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File';
        }
```